# Help translating 1940 Fraktur font from Google snippet view

Tags: german-to-english, blackletter

In 1941, [Eduard Willeke](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eduard_Willeke), a German social scientist and economist wrote a journal article titled "[Der Arbeitseinsatz im Kriege](https://www.jstor.org/stable/23817886)" (The use of labour during the war) and made the following claim:

> So konnten noch für die Hackfruchternte 1939 rund 300000 polnische
> Kriegsgefangene, vor allem zunächst im Osten des Reiches, zum Einsatz
> gebracht werden1).

[Translation](https://www.deepl.com/translator#de/en/So%20konnten%20noch%20f%C3%BCr%20die%20Hackfruchternte%201939%20rund%20300000%20polnische%20Kriegsgefangene%2C%20vor%20allem%20zun%C3%A4chst%20im%20Osten%20des%20Reiches%2C%20zum%20Einsatz%20gebracht%20werden.):

> Thus, around 300,000 Polish prisoners of war could still be used for the root crop harvest in 1939, mainly initially in the east of the Reich 1).

To back up this claim he references "[Reichs-Arbeitsblatt](https://onlinebooks.library.upenn.edu/webbin/serial?id=reichsarbeitsblatt)", which was a journal of German labour published by the German government:

> 1) Vgl. HöLK, Der Einsatz von Kriegsgefangenen in Arbeitsstellen, „Reichsarbeitsblatt"
> 1940, V, S. 352.

While [Google Books have copies of Reichs-Arbeitsblatt](https://books.google.co.uk/books?q=editions:LCCN09124768&id=UDTCCW8B9iEC) they are restricted to snippet view. However, I was able to find an [edition from 1940](https://books.google.co.uk/books?lr=&id=lpI3TsDimIUC&dq=editions%3ALCCN09124768&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=polnische%20Kriegsgefangene%20000) that seemed to reference the 300,000 Polish prisoners but I and [free OCR tools](https://onlineocrconverter.com/free-ocr-in-german-fraktur) can't read the German Fraktur font:

[image: Reichs-Arbeitsblatt, 1940]

Is anyone able to translate or transcribe the text from the snippet view?

Comment: Presumably off-topic (bulk-translation), but left column only? (Right one does not continue seamlessly).

Comment: Yeah could be off-topic, all I need is a transcription of the left column which @Janka has provided.

Comment: Little nitpick about DeepL's translation: Instead of "still", it should be "already". The assault on Poland started September 1st, 1939, and what they're saying in the German text is that already for the root crop harvest in that same year, 300 000 Polish war prisoners "could be used".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> … Intensivierung der eigenen Landwirtschaft selbst einen großen Eigenbedarf haben. Bekanntlich sollen bis zu einer Million polnische Arbeitskräfte eingesetzt werden. Allerdings ist diese Zahl bei weitem noch nicht erreicht worden, auch wenn man die rund 300 000 Kriegsgefangenen berücksichtigt. Die Schwierigkeiten bei der Anwerbung sind zur Zeit nicht gering, da einmal die Hetze gegen alles Deutsche noch nachwirkt und andererseits auch immer wieder eine feindliche „Flüsterpropaganda“ neue Greuelmärchen zu verbreiten sucht. Wie haltlos diese sind, davon können sich alle polnischen Arbeitskräfte überzeugen.

> … rechtzeitig zu beantragen. Umfang der Sozialversicherung. Nachträglich sei noch auf die Ausführungen „Die soziale Wendung” in Heft 8 der Zeitschrift „Die Bank” hingewiesen, weil hier zusammenfassend eine Übersicht über den Bereich der staatlichen Rentenversicherung gegeben wird. Von der Zahlenangaben seien folgende erwähnt. Nach den Zählergebnissen vom 17. Mai 1939 umfaßt das Großdeutsche Reich eine Bevölkerung von 79,36 Millionen, wovon 69,32 Millionen auf das Altreich, 6,64 Millionen auf die Ostmark und 3,41 Millionen auf das Sudeten[land entfallen].

Comment: Thanks, was that done by hand or did a tool help you?

Comment: I did it manually. Reading Fraktur isn't that difficult. Of course it helps if you know the words that could match the pattern. Even half-lines are sufficient for decoding then.